# Cant upload file to azure blob storage using media plugin

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi i'm using xamarin and I'm trying to upload a photo from my phone to azure using the media plugin and azure blob storage. Here's my code:

```
async void selectImage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            var image = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            //System.IO.Stream stream = t;

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = sermonsContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

            using (var fileStream = image)
            {
                blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }

        }
```

however i'm getting the error: Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile' to 'System.IO.Stream' (CS1503) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
async void selectImage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    var image = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

    //System.IO.Stream stream = t;

    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = sermonsContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

    using (var fileStream = image.GetStream ())
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is code which I use to get stream of image

```
var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(options);
            if (photo != null)
            {
                return ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                {
                    return photo.GetStream();
                });
            }
```